# Removing taxonomy base using WP rewrite

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I´m trying to create the following URL structure:

```
example.com/attractions                     <-- post type archive
example.com/attractions/taxonomy_term       <-- taxonomy archive
example.com/attractions/van-gogh-museum     <-- custom post type
```

Unfortunately this isn´t possible by default: WordPress needs the taxonomy base in the URL, as SE user sanchothefat wrote in his answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/custom-permalink-structure):

> *...if you don't want the taxonomy-slug to be there then you're out of
>   luck, you can't have the same slug as your post type or another
>   taxonomy as it won't know what term is from which taxonomy and what's
>   a post.*

In other words, WordPress needs this permalink structure:

```
example.com/attractions/taxonomy_base/taxonomy_term
```

**My question:**
Is there a way to make this work using WordPress rewrite API?

I suppose it involves 2 steps:

1. Removing the taxonomy base from the URL
2. Tell WordPress what post type it needs to display

---

### Update #1

I found a code snippet that should remove the taxonomy base from the URL:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['taxonomy_base'] = array('%taxonomy_base%', EP_NONE);
```

([Source](http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/675) - see last answer on bottom of page)

This isn´t the complete solution though, since WordPress can´t tell if the post is a taxonomy archive or a post type...

---

### Update #2

The author of this [great article](http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/) on *Advanced Taxonomy Queries with Pretty URLs* wrote me:

> *What you're asking isn't too difficult, but it could be a bit tricky.
>   The rewrite rules need to know what type of thing the second term
>   is(..) That's why the category/tag/taxonomy name prefix is prepended.
>   You could create a rewrite so that *everything* after /attractions/ is
>   treated as a taxonomy URL, but doing both gets a little tricky.*

---

### Update #3

For anyone having the same issue, have a look at [this discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9419/remove-taxonomy-slug-from-a-custom-hierarchical-taxonomy-permalink) on WordPress Answers. Especially MikeSchinkel´s plugin code might help.

Here´s an interesting example of WPCandy combining the taxonomy base and term in the URL: `http://wpcandy.com/pros/experienced/with-multisite`

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I moved on to other things after update #3. I still need to find a solution for this issue though.

Answer (score 1):

I just added a plugin to the Wordpress Directory that removes the slug base for any custom taxonomy and the default category taxonomy. You can find it here - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-taxonomy-base/

Answer (score 1):

Recently I came across the same situation, and after a day spent searching for a solution and couldn't find any, I wrote my own **working** solution.

The trick is to use Wordpress wp_rewrite, and to add your URLs to it when Wordpress generates its permalinks on the beginning.

I've wrote a simple function to do it all automatically and explained everything on my blog (don't want to paste the same code twice), so feel free to check it out ;)

http://someweblog.com/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-with-same-slug-as-custom-post-type/

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.