# How to remove base tags at the wordpress

Tags: tags

How to remove base prefix from the tags without needing a plugin, because the plugins that existed were discontinued.

Comment: Hi Jose! Can you provide some additional details? Is there a prefix on your tag term names? Or are you referring to something else? Can you provide some practical examples as well?

Comment: Hello, I'm referring to the tag pages. www.blog.com/tag/tagname. I would like to delete the prefix tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing taxonomy base using WP rewrite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32934/removing-taxonomy-base-using-wp-rewrite)